# Pronunciation and the usage of 啊

Tags: grammar, usage, pronunciation

So what does the word 啊 actually use for? I have seen it being use for some sentence but don’t really know when to use it

Also my teacher said to me that depending on the word 啊 goes with it will have different pronunciation. For example if it goes with 来 or 走 she told me 啊 kinda read out like “yà” while with看 or 想 the 啊 like become part of the pronunciation so ”看啊” is spoken like “kàn’à”

Comment: 啊is always pronounced as a, with different tones, but not ya, that is a different character呀, which doesn't have too much semantic difference. Depending on dialects, 啊or呀 may be used more or less often.

Comment: cf. ＂对外汉语常用词语对比例释＂ ＂啊＂ **受前一音节尾音的影响** ，常发生几种音变现象。具体规则如下。１。前一音节尾音是  a、e、i、u 的，读作 ＂ia＂，写作＂呀＂：爬呀 唱歌呀 来呀真累呀 吃鱼呀 ２。前一音尾音是 u、ou、ao 的，读作 ＂ua＂，写作＂哇＂：哭哇 快修哇 游哇 多好哇 要哇 ３。前一音节尾音是 n 的，读作 ＂na＂，写作＂哪＂：干哪 喊哪 戒烟哪 真热心哪 ４。有时，还会出现与前一音节合音的现象，即前一音节声母与＂a＂合为一个音节。（１）前一个词是＂了＂的，＂了＋ 啊＂读作＂la＂，写作＂啦＂：长这么高啦 不走啦 学会啦 住了五年啦（２）前一个词是＂呢＂的，＂呢 ＋ 啊＂读作＂na＂，写作＂哪＂：时间还早着哪 天热着哪 自尊心强着哪

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your teacher's opinion, it seems like she would want to use 呀 for the desired pronunciation *yà*.

Though, 啊 does have many tones, it can express feeling of ***surprise*** in first and third tone, it can express the meaning of ***asking*** in second tone, it can express meaning of ***adorable***, ***getting it*** or ***surprise*** in fourth tone.

It can also mean a lot in its light tone.

You would be able to find all those in a dictionary, but keep in mind, it is not that strict, so use your intuition.